# Is something wrong with my confidence interval for a Binomial variable?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X$ be a Binomial random variable with parameters $n$ and $p$. I came up with the following very simple approach to finding a confidence interval for $p$, but the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) on confidence intervals uses much more complicated methods, which makes me feel there must be something wrong with my idea.

Let's say we want a $95\%$ confidence interval. The question is: how can we find a value $\epsilon$ so that

$$P(|\frac X n - p|>\epsilon) \leq 0.05$$

Well, applying Tchebyshev's inequality:

$$P(|\frac X n - p|>\epsilon) \leq \frac {\text{Var}(\frac X n)} {\epsilon^2}$$

And $\text{Var}(\frac X n)=\frac 1 {n} p(1-p)\leq \frac 1 {4n} $. Thus

$$P(|\frac X n - p|>\epsilon) \leq \frac {1} {4n\epsilon^2}$$

Setting the right hand side equal to $0.05$, we can find an appropriate value of $\epsilon$. Then, whatever result we get when we do our experiment, we know there's a $95\%$ chance that $p$ is within $\epsilon$ of that value.

Is something wrong? Or am I misunderstanding what that Wikipedia page is about?

Comment: A more exact way is to do a normal approximation.

Comment: The Chebyshev Inequality is very weak. For most "nice" distributions, it gives bounds which, though correct, are quite pessimistic. The probability that $|X/n-p|\gt \epsilon$ is, for the binomial, usually much less than $\text{Var}(X/n)/\epsilon^2$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Does my method at least generate a valid confidence interval, or have I misunderstood the definition of a confidence interval? Because usually a confidence interval is defined as a random variable depending on $X$, but mine is constant.

Comment: The confidence interval for $p$ will involve $X/n$, it will be $X/n-\epsilon\lt p\lt X/n+\epsilon$ for the $\epsilon$ that you find. That $\epsilon$ will be too big, but not wrong, As an analogy, suppose I ask you to find a positive integer $t$ such that $t^2\gt 15$. If you say $t=47$ you will have found a correct $t$.

Comment: To find a confidence interval for p, we must assume $X$ is fixed. Then $X/n$ is the $\hat{p}$ in wiki