# Approximation of Binomial RV

Tags: probability, inequality, approximation, binomial-distribution

Coin binomial. Proportion p defective, (1-p) fair. We take samples of n coins: $X_n$ random RV equal to the number of defective coins.

Show that for any $\epsilon > 0$ $P(|\frac {X_n} {n} - p| \geq \epsilon) \leq \frac {1} {4n\epsilon^2}$

I tried showing it using a form of Chebyshev's inequality:

$P({|X - \mu| \geq k}) \leq \frac {\sigma^2} {k^2}$

By multiplying by n, and rewriting based on E[X_n]:

$P(|X_n - \mu| \geq \epsilon n) \leq \frac {(np(1-p))^2} {(\epsilon n)^2}$, simplified to:

$P(|X_n - \mu| \geq \epsilon n) \leq \frac {(p(1-p))^2} {\epsilon ^2}$, but from here I have no idea how to get to the following step.

Thought about CLT as well, but couldn't see the 1/4 coming up.

Comment: Explaines in this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1599750/305862 as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Confidence intervals explanation as well, cool!

Comment: @JeanMarie if I'm asked to give a condition on n, such that $\frac {X_n} {n} $ is close to p within $10^{-2}$ with probability $\geq$ than 95% - can I use the technique in that answer? (Basically Chebyshev?) 

Using that technique I got $n \leq 500$ after setting $\epsilon$ to $10^{-2}$

(Or should I use the normal approximation?)

Comment: I think you have to use this technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variance of binomial is $np(1-p)$ which shouldn't be squared. That will give you the $1/n$ factor, and you can get the $1/4$ factor by maximizing $p(1-p)$ over $p\in (0,1).$